# How to recover a deleted Newsletter in Content builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I deleted a newsletter in the content builder by mistake. Is there any way to recover that Newsletter?

Comment: You can try to involve SF Support. sfmc does not have a "recycle bin" frontend like sales cloud, which you yourself could access to recover things you deleted. There are recovery options for support in some areas, possibly also content builder.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-box option for this.

Salesforce Support was able to recover content in the [**Classic Content Builder**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_import_content_faqs.htm&type=5) some time ago.

> In emergency situations, Global Support can retrieve deleted content and restore them in your account.

Therefore I would suggest asking SF support asking if they are able to recover current Content Builder content for you.